# Audit/Log in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce

We need to log specific action in MVC 3 project. A database table will store logs something like:

"User [**SessionUserHere...**] changed [**Name**][**Lastname**][**OtherAttributesHere...**] values of [**ChangedEmployeeHere...**]"

I need to learn which attributes of a model changed and which ones keep their original values.
Is there any way to track which attributes of a Model changed?

In [MVC3 doing Audit trail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658821/mvc3-doing-audit-trail) a database trigger is proposed; but we use Sql Server Compact for this project.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Have you had look at the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do the audit in code rather than the database.  In the HttpPost handler, get the original value and compare the objects using an auditing function.  I have a home brew implementation, but this does a similar thing [Compare .NET Objects](http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/).

It means you can do the following:

```
var original = GetDatabaseRecord(xx);
var newRec = GetFormSubmission();  // However you do this

var auditor = new CompareObjects();

if ( auditor.Compare(original, newRec) )
{
    foreach ( var diff in auditor.Differences )
    {
        // work through the deltas
    }
}
else
{
    // Nothing changed!
}
```

My own version returns a structure of:

- Name (such as "Issue.Priority")
- Change (ChangedValue, OnlyLeft, OnlyRight)
- Old Value
- New Value

The link provided may suffice for you or act as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I created a library to do just this and provide some additional metadata.  It relies on MVC `ModelMetadata` and `DataAnnotations` to provide a "readable version" of the diff for non technical users.

https://github.com/paultyng/ObjectDiff

Given objects like (no metadata obviously):

```
var before = new 
{ 
    Property1 = "", 
    MultilineText = "abc\ndef\nghi", 
    ChildObject = new { ChildProperty = 7 }, 
    List = new string[] { "a", "b" } 
};

var after = new 
{ 
    Property1 = (string)null, 
    MultilineText = "123\n456", 
    NotPreviouslyExisting = "abc", 
    ChildObject = new { ChildProperty = 6 }, 
    List = new string[] { "b", "c" } 
};
```

It would output something like:

```
ChildObject - ChildProperty: '6', was '7'
List - [2, added]: 'c', was not present
List - [removed]: No value present, was 'a'
MultilineText: 
-----
123
456
-----
was 
-----
abc
def
ghi
-----
NotPreviouslyExisting: 'abc', was not present
```

Comment: does this have any kind of support for translation or do I have to fork the code and modify it?